# hide a message after 30 seconds.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can after click on button show a message and next **hide it after 30 seconds**?

**Like:**

```
$('#message').live('click', function() {
    $('#sm').hide();
    $('#sm').hide().show('slow').html('You have successfully registered');
    // how is hide "$('#sm')" after 30 seconds??
});
```

Please give me example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#message').live('click', function() {
    $('#sm').hide().show('slow').html('You have successfully registered');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#sm').hide(); }, 30000);
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/LEgPB/)

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#sm').hide();
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 3):

in your third line you write:

```
$('#sm').hide().show('slow').html('You have successfully registered').delay(30000).hide();
```

hope it works

Comment: From the docs on [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/): "this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue"

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) it takes a function and milliseconds as parameter. In your case it would be something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#sm').hide() ; }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either javascript's native [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function or jQuery's [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. If you choose the latter all you have to do is add:

```
.delay(30000).hide();
```

at the end of your existing code like so:

```
$('#sm').hide().show('slow').html('You have successfully registered').delay(30000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: From the docs on [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/): "this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue"

Comment: @sje397 good point, when I used delay() I used fadeIn() instead of show() so in this case the problem can be alleviated using fadeOut() instead of hide() or if OP doesn't want any effects then just using setTimeout would do.